# Routing error with Rails 3 with members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following route in rails 3:

```
resources :jobs do 
    member do 
      post :seller_job_submitted
    end
  end
```

And the following form

```
=form_for job, :url=>seller_job_submitted_job_path(job), :remote=>true do |f|
```

I know it's not very restful, but it's kind of a stop gap for now. In any case, I keep getting this error when submitting the form

```
Started POST "/jobs/74/seller_job_submitted" for 127.0.0.1    
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/jobs/74/seller_job_submitted"):
```

but when I run `rake routes | grep seller_job_submitted`, I think the correct results come up:

```
seller_job_submitted_job POST   /jobs/:id/seller_job_submitted(.:format)                  {:action=>"seller_job_submitted", :controller=>"jobs"}
```

Any ideas about what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted your server after editing the routes file?

Comment: Yes.  Definitely thought this could be the problem.  But its not :(

Comment: Yes this is a regression bug with Rails 3. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have defined method seller_job_submitted in model and controller.
Replace your code with

```
resources :jobs    
match "jobs/:id/seller_job_submitted" => "jobs#seller_job_submitted", :as => "seller_job_submitted"
```

Then in form_for tag use `:url=>seller_job_submitted_path`

This should fix your problem: you did not define seller_job_submitted_job_path explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `put` instead of `post`? Or use `:post` as the method in the submit form.

You can tell if this is the issue by looking at what the REST method is for the generated form (look for the hidden field in the page source).

So in short, maybe Rails is somehow expecting a `POST` on that URL but it's receiving a `PUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a regression bug with Rails 3.
It turns out you need to be careful about using POST in your routes.rb.

```
resources :jobs do
   member do
   post :seller_job_submitted # will not work
   put  :seller_job_submitted # will just work
end
```

This is even though the FORM method says POST.