# Mysterious AbstractController::ActionNotFound (Route is there)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

(Rails 3.0.7)

My `routes.rb` has this:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :campus_hub do
    resources :billing_subscriptions, {
      :except => [:destroy, :new, :create]
    } do
      member do
        post :add_addon
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`rake routes` shows this route:

```
add_addon_admin_campus_hub_billing_subscription POST   /admin/campus_hub/billing_subscriptions/:id/add_addon(.:format)                            {:action=>"add_addon", :controller=>"admin/campus_hub/billing_subscriptions"}
```

My controller (`Admin::CampusHub::BillingSubscriptionsController`) has the method `add_addon`.

I do a POST that looks like this in the logs:

```
Started POST "/admin/campus_hub/billing_subscriptions/50059f5be628f83b13000012/add_addon" for 33.33.33.1 at Tue Jul 17 20:21:17 +0200 2012
```

And I get this error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '50059f5be628f83b13000012' could not be found for Admin::CampusHub::BillingSubscriptionsController)
```

I'm totally baffled.  The POST request I make matches the route exactly.  Why does it think that the ID is the action?  Hope I'm just missing something obvious!

Comment: yes, edit/update routes are working fine.

Comment: A workaround is to define verb for the routes as GET instead of POST/DELETE.  Then it works.

Comment: Can you pust your code in an answer?

Comment: you change `post :add_addon` to `get :add_addon`.  And it's not an answer.  It's a workaround.  I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity can you change it to be just `post :add_on` and not use the member block?  You can still access the parameter, it will just be prefixed differently.

Comment: could you add the code for `Admin::CampusHub::BillingSubscriptionsController`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work at that company anymore, no access to the source code.

Comment: This does look like some odd action call from within the controller action... For instance (render params[:id]) in add_addon code

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from the rails version that you're having a similar problem to this: [Routing error with Rails 3 with members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868081/routing-error-with-rails-3-with-members) which is a bug in rails 3, note comment: [Routing error with Rails 3 with members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868081/routing-error-with-rails-3-with-members#comment7306038_4868081)

You'd need to replace:

```
  member do
    post :add_addon
  end
```

With something like this:

```
match "add_addon" => "billing_subscriptions#add_addon", :as => :add_addon, :via => :post
```

You'd get a slightly swapped path like this: `admin_campus_hub_billing_subscription_add_addon_path` but it should work in rails 3 and 4.

All together it's like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :campus_hub do
    resources :billing_subscriptions, {
      :except => [:destroy, :new, :create]
    } do
      match "add_addon" => "billing_subscriptions#add_addon", :as => :add_addon, :via => :post
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the full rake routes looks like this:

```
admin_campus_hub_billing_subscription_add_addon POST  /admin/campus_hub/billing_subscriptions/:billing_subscription_id/add_addon(.:format) admin/campus_hub/billing_subscriptions#add_addon
```